# How to run a function on a separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i have a *function* that i want to **run on a separate thread**.

My question is, do i have to create the function's object in the new thread in order for him to run on a separate thread or i can create the object on the ui thread and just run the *function* in a new thread?

Some sample code:

```
var foo = new object();

foo.functionCall(); // run on new thread
```

Comment: I have won the oscar for the most devotes 

Comment: no actually there are other winners that have you beat.. but on a side note, what have you tried on your own..? have you done any actual real research.

Comment: Haven't, thought to ask before

Comment: well good luck, come back and let us know where you stand once you get something started.

Comment: Tomorrow i have access to my computer, then i will try to research.

Comment: You‘d better do that. And one tip: don‘t do multithreading if you don‘t understand the implications. It seems to me that you don‘t have a clear image what a thread is and that resources are shared between them.

Comment: I know how to multithread. It&#39;s just this specific question messes with my mind.

I find it amazing that I can't get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Task.Run(() => foo.functionCall());
```

But as Sefe said: Read the doku!!! 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even though I appreciate your answer, can you explain me why.

Comment: If you enter "How to run a function on a separate thread c#" in your favourite search engine, you get at least 100 of answers how to start a new thread in c# (my search engine returned the posted answer on position two). So if you ask this questions on stackoverflow it looks like you did not investigate any time in your problem at all... (which would be against the rules of stack overflow see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This was the top result when I searched for it. :D